# Passing json string as an input to one of the parameters of a POST request body in RESTAssured with Selenium

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am using RESTAssured java library in Selenium for API test automation. I need to pass a json string as a value to one parameter of a POST request body. My request body looks like this:

```
{
  "parameter1": "abc",
  "parameter2": "def",
  "parameter3": {
    "id": "",
    "key1": "test123",
    "prod1": {
      "id": "",
      "key3": "test123",
      "key4": "12334",
      "key5": "3",
      "key6": "234334"
    },
    "prod2": {
      "id": "",
      "key7": "test234",
      "key8": "1",
      "key9": true
    }
  },
  "parameter4": false,
  "parameter5": "ghi"
}
```

For parameter3 I need to be pass a string value in json format. The json file is located in my local system and is a huge file, so it would make sense if I can pass the path to the json file.

Is there any way using RestAssured to achieve this?

Comment: json object is not valid. please update a valid json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [org.json](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html) library;

Read json file and get as a String

```
String content = "";
try {
    content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("absolute_path_to_file\\example.json")));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Covert the String to JSONObject

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
```

Get the new json object that you need to put in the `jsonObject`

```
String jsonString = "{\n" +
        "  \"firstName\": \"John\",\n" +
        "  \"lastName\" : \"doe\",\n" +
        "  \"age\"      : 26,\n" +
        "  \"address\"  : {\n" +
        "    \"streetAddress\": \"naist street\",\n" +
        "    \"city\"         : \"Nara\",\n" +
        "    \"postalCode\"   : \"630-0192\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}";

JSONObject updateObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Replace the value of `parameter3` with new `updateObject`

```
jsonObject.put("parameter3", updateObject);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

If you beautify the printed output;

```
{
  "parameter5": "ghi",
  "parameter4": false,
  "parameter3": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "address": {
      "streetAddress": "naist street",
      "city": "Nara",
      "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "age": 26
  },
  "parameter2": "def",
  "parameter1": "abc"
}
```

If you want to update a nested json object like `prod1` in `parameter3`

```
JSONObject parameter3JsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("parameter3");
parameter3JsonObject.put("prod1", updateObject);
```